# javascriptの整数の値すべてを条件にしたい

Tags: javascript

この`value="11111"`の数字の部分を整数すべてを条件にするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

```
if ($dd.find('option[value="11111"]').length)
```

全体のコード

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
      $(".accordionbox dt").filter(function (i, e) {
        return isActive($(e).next());
      }).each(function (i, e) {
        return toggle($(e));
      });
      $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function () {
        toggle($(this));
      });
    });

    function toggle($dt) {
      $dt.next().slideToggle(100);//slide speed 0.1second
      //
      if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
        //
        $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
      } else {
        //
        $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
      };
    };

    //
    function isActive($dd) {

  if ($dd.find('input[value="email"]:checked').length) 
    return true;

  if ($dd.find('option[value="11111"]').length)
    return true;
    return false;
}
;
</script>
```

Comment: 編集時にコード部分を選択した状態で `{}` をクリックすると見やすく表示されるようになるので、次回から試してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

セレクタだけで実現できないと思われます。セレクタは`'option'`だけにして、`filter()` で絞り込むと良いでしょう。

```
if ($dd.find('option').filter(function() { return /^[0-9]+$/.test(this.value); }).length)
```

Comment: ありがとうござます。うまくいきました。